# Phing and Wordpress configuration

Tags: php, phing

I'm using Phing to push a wordpress installation to my production server. Is it possible to define the wp-config properties inside my build file, and then have phing replace the wp-config contents to use those variables?

Like this:

```
<property name="prod.db_name" value="wordpress" />
<property name="prod.db_user" value="root" />
<property name="prod.db_password" value="toor" />
<property name="prod.db_host" value="prod.host.com" />
```

I then want a phing task which takes those values and replaces my wp-config with the correct properties.

How would i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think it is. Searching in the [phing documentation](http://phing.info/docs/guide/current/) led me to the CopyTask (appendix B), and the ReplaceRegexp filter (appendix D2).

Try to include this task in your build target (after defining your properties):

```
<copy file="./config-sample.php" tofile="./config.php">
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregexp>
      <regexp pattern="(define\('DB_NAME', ')\w+('\);)" replace="\1${prod.db_name}\2"/>
      <regexp pattern="(define\('DB_USER', ')\w+('\);)" replace="\1${prod.db_user}\2"/>
      <regexp pattern="(define\('DB_PASSWORD', ')\w+('\);)" replace="\1${prod.db_password}\2"/>
      <regexp pattern="(define\('DB_HOST', ')\w+('\);)" replace="\1${prod.db_host}\2"/>
    </replaceregexp>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

This task will copy config-sample.php (provided in the wordpress distribution) to config.php, performing a file transformation through regex replacement filters, thus overwriting the example parameters to your wanted values.

You might want to configure other parameters as well, like DB encoding & collate, security parameters (at least those ones), table prefix, language...

Comment: @streetpc But can you please tell me is the any way to do it with the same file without using <copy operation?

Comment: @SeniorDev Looks like the ReflexiveTask (appendix B) http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#ReflexiveTask